# XPS or XAML viewer to embed in .NET app?

Tags: xaml, xps, xpsviewer

Is there a viewer object or ActiveX control I can use to embed an XPS document, or an XAML  GUI in my .NET application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ElementHost Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) to host WPF content on a .Net Windows Form.The ElementHost appears in the Toolbox under the WPF Interoperability section.
You can then host a WPF control that has XPS Document Viewer on it and you've solved both problems.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps.
[Integrating WPF with Windows Forms](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/WinFormWPFIntegration.aspx)