# How do I display an XPS document in Access?

Tags: ole, xps

I have some XPS report and want to display that inside an Access form. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to integrate XPS in an Access document is [with a web browser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425605/xps-or-xaml-viewer-to-embed-in-net-app#). Select the "Design" from the form layout tools and add a new web browser control. Then set the `Control Source` to the desired .xps document.

There are probably some scroll bars to the sides of the control. Those are from the xps viewer object and I have no clue how to remove them.